# Solving hard Trigonometric Equations

Tags: trigonometry

I want to solve the equation 
\begin{align*}
\sin(p x^2)=0, \quad p\neq0\in \mathbb{R}, x\in[0,\pi]
\end{align*}
Since $\sin(px^2)$ is highly oscillaotry depending upon $p$. How to find all roots in the interval $[0,\pi]$.
If we solve 
\begin{align*}
px^2=\sin^{-1}(0)=n\pi
\implies x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{n\pi}{p}}.
\end{align*}
How to solve this equation when oscillations depend upon $p$.

Comment: What do you mean by "oscillations depend upon $p$"?

Comment: If we plot the function and choose large value of $p$, graph of $\sin(px^2)$ has large frequecy means more roots in the interval $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 3):

Short remark: If $p$ is negative, then the solution of $px^2=n\pi$ only exists for **negative** values of $n$, while for positive values of $p$, the solution exists only for **positive** values of $n$, and of course $n=0$.

As the solution set for negative $p$'s is similar to the one for positive $p$, I will assume $p>0$ from now on (but in a full answer, be careful!)

---

If you are **given** a particular value of $p$, then $$\pm\sqrt{\frac{n\pi}{p}}$$ is a solution for every $n\in\mathbb Z$. Using the restriction $x\in[0,\pi]$, the possible solutions are $$\left\{0,  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{p}}, \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{p}}, \sqrt{\frac{3\pi}{p}}, \dots, \sqrt{\frac{N\pi}{p}}\right\}$$

where $N=\lfloor p\cdot \pi\rfloor$.

This is because if $\sqrt{\frac{n\pi}{p}}<\pi\iff n<p\pi$.

---

Clearly, the larger the value of $p$, the more solutions there will be -  for $p=1$, there are only $4$ solutions $\{0,\sqrt{\pi}, \sqrt{2\pi}, \sqrt{3\pi}\}$, but for large values of $p$, the number of solutions grows with a factor of $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks.....I got the point :).

Comment: In the question $p$ could be negative, so $|p|$ should be used.